# intelliJ 12 - cannot find the xml file i want it to

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to get, when i press the little green "run me" button in intelliJ, the running program to pick up and use this file (in the project structure)

```
/src/config/some_folder/some_xml.xml
```

However, when i press that green run button, intelliJ 12 is giving me this error:

Resource not found on classpath using context ClassLoader: some_folder/some_xml.xml

In an attempt to resolve, this, I have this in my Settings:Compiler: Resource patterns

```
!?*.java;!?*.form;!?*.class;!?*.groovy;!?*.scala;!?*.flex;!?*.kt;!?*.cl;?*.xml;?*.config
```

note the penultimate xml entry.

I also unchecked the "use external build" button. I do not know what it means or does, but I read somewhere that it should not be used.

I also have these (among other entries) in Project Structure:Modules: Sources tab

```
config
config\some_folder
```

Marked in blue (sources) under the Source Folders heading.

There is no fancy pom.xml for this project - it is an old legacy project. If i add a pom.xml to resolve this, where would i put it, what would i put in it (in entirety) and would i need to tell intelliJ i now have a pom.xml?

**EDIT** ok, so intelliJ can find the file when i refer to it as

```
./config/some_folder/some_xml.xml
```

but will not find it if it is reffered to as

```
some_folder/some_xml.xml
```

I think this is the real issue - how do i resolve this?

Comment: Are using it for android development?

Comment: Please share a sample project that reproduces this problem.

Answer (score 1):

src/config needs to be configured in the project as a resources folder. In the project tray, right click /src/config and select "Mark Directory As" -> "Source Root"